Navigation to Index view using RedirectToAction does not work (C#)
While debugging the code, I see that the Edit action is performed, but the URL remains unchanged and there is no navigation to the new Index view. I also tried to handle the form submission via JavaScript, but after saving the Java Script code was not executed.
Controller.cs:
[HttpGet("/ZahtevaZaReaktivacijo/[controller]/[action]/{zahtevaId}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int zahtevaId)
{
    ZahtevaZaReaktivacijoInfo? zahtevaInfo;

    zahtevaInfo = await _zahtevaService.GetZahtevaZaReaktivacijoInfoById(zahtevaId);


    if (zahtevaInfo == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    return PartialView("_Index", zahtevaInfo);
}

[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Save(ZahtevaZaReaktivacijoInfo zahtevaZaReaktivacijoInfo)
{
    ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(zahtevaZaReaktivacijoInfo);

    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return PartialView("_Index", zahtevaZaReaktivacijoInfo);
    }

    try
    {
        int newId = await zahtevaService.NovaZahteva(zahtevaZaReaktivacijoInfo);
        ViewData["NotifySaveSuccessText"] = ResourceUI.UI_Message_Saved; // Sporočimo na UX, da je uspešno shranjeno

        if (newId > 0)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Edit", new { zahtevaId = newId });
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("ModelException", ExceptionHandler.HandleModelException(ex));
        Log.ForContext(typeof(PodruznicaController)).Error(ex, ex.Message);
    }

    return PartialView("_Index", zahtevaZaReaktivacijoInfo);
}

Index.cshtml:
@model ZahtevaZaReaktivacijoInfo
@{
    string tabContentId = "EditZadeva_" + Model.ZahtevaId;
    string urlFormAction = "Save";
    string urlClose = Url.Content("~/");

    bool isDodajanje = Model.ZahtevaId == 0;
    bool isFormLocked = true;

    string isReadonly = isDodajanje ? "" : "form-lockable-item";
}

<div id="@tabContentId" class=" ">
    <div class="row">   
        <div class="col-12">
            <!-- .card-body -->
            <div class="card-body p-2">

                <form id="@(tabContentId)form"
                      asp-action="@urlFormAction"
                      data-urlclose="@urlClose"
                      method="post"
                      rrc-change-checker="true"
                      class="form-lockable">

                    <input type="hidden" asp-for="EnotaId" />
                    <input type="hidden" asp-for="ZahtevaId" />
                    <input type="hidden" asp-for="SysRowversion" />

                      <div class=" ">
                    <partial name="_ValidationSummaryPartial" model="Model" view-data="ViewData" />
                    </div>

                    <div class="section-block">
                        <div class="h6 text-uppercase">PODATKI O ZAHTEVI ZA REAKTIVACIJO</div>
                        <!-- .card -->
                        <div class="card mx-0">
                            <!-- .card-body -->
                            <div class="card-body p-2 pr-3 col-12 resize-section">
                                <div class="form-group row">
                                    <label asp-for="RazlogZahteveId"
                                           rrc-required-css-class="model-required"
                                           class="control-label col-sm-5">
                                    </label>
                                    <input asp-for="RazlogZahteveId"
                                           class="form-control col-sm-7  @isReadonly"
                                           kendo-type="kendoDropDownList"
                                           kendo-filter="contains"
                                           kendo-api="@Url.Content("~/api/Sifrant/SifrantByVrstaIdDropdownList/" + SifrantVrsta.RazlogZahteveZaReaktivacijo.Id)">
                                </div>
                            </div><!-- /.card-body -->
                        </div><!-- /.card- -->
                    </div><!-- /.section-block- -->

                    <div class="card-divider"></div>

                    <div class="section-block d-flex">
                        @* form buttons *@
                        <button type="submit" class="form-save btn btn-primary ml-auto"><i class="fa-light fa-save fa-lg mr-1"></i> @ResourceUI.UI_Form_Button_Save</button>
                        <button type="button" class="form-close-up1level2parameters btn btn-secondary ml-2"><i class="fa-light fa-arrow-left-to-line fa-lg mr-1"></i> @ResourceUI.UI_Form_Button_Exit</button>
                    </div>
                </form>

            </div> <!-- ./card-bod -->
        </div> <!-- ./card -->
    </div> <!-- ./section-block -->
</div> <!-- ./row tabContentId -->

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        kendoHelper.genericComponents.bind("#@tabContentId");  // bind generic kendo elements
        changeChecker.init("#@tabContentId");                  // bind User notification on form change
        asyncFormHandler.init("#@tabContentId");               // bind Form submit events
        asyncFormHandler.enableOrDisableForm("#@tabContentId", '@(isFormLocked)');

        $('#EditZadeva_3form').closest('.tab-pane').attr('id')
        $('#EditZadeva_3form').closest('.tabs-container').find('a[href="#Zahteva"]')

        showValueChangeAlert.init("#@tabContentId");
    });
</script>

Route config:


// Route configuration
app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "defaultArea",
    pattern: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");



Any suggestions what is wrong?

it seems like the redirection in your Save action is not updating the URL as expected. It because of returning partial view and the behave is correct that URL won't change.
Do you want to keep your back-end code or front-end code because I want to post the answer.

No, please post the answer. @AliHemmati

I had a test in my side with your codes(commenting the parts that used to handle data), when I click the submit button in the _Index.cshtml, it will trigger the Save method. Then if it runs return PartialView("_Index", zahtevaZaReaktivacijoInfo);, I will see the url to be https://localhost:7252/Zahteva/Save. If It runs return RedirectToAction("Edit", new { zahtevaId = 11 });, the url will be https://localhost:7252/Zahteva/Edit?zahtevaId=11. Could you pls let me know what you want to get ultimately?
